# Javascript sort() is not sorting correctly

Tags: javascript

Trying to sort an array and sort() is switching just 1 value and adding the largest to the middle of the array. Could anyone help me understand what is happening?
My Results that I get are:

```
Original Array: [2643832795, 1, "3", 10, 3, 5]
New Array: [1, 10, 2643832795, 3, 3, 5]
```

```
let startArray = [2643832795, 1, "3", 10, 3, 5];

function bigSorting(unsorted) {
    let newArray = [];

    unsorted.forEach(el => { 
        if(typeof(el) == "string") 
        { newArray.push(parseInt(el)) }
        else { newArray.push(parseInt(el)) }
    });

    newArray.sort();

    console.log(startArray);
    console.log(newArray);
}

bigSorting(startArray);
```

Comment: [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) without callback is treating all values as string an sort these strings. that is the standard habit of it.

Comment: Thank you for this resource @NinaScholz , it helped me get this solved!

Comment: its sorting alphabetical order

Answer (score 1):

It's using lexical comparison of strings.  You can use a comparison function that coerces to numbers and subtracts for comparison

```js
let startArray = [2643832795, 1, "3", 10, 3, 5];

function bigSorting(unsorted) {
    let newArray = [];

    unsorted.forEach(el => { 
        if(typeof(el) == "string") 
        { newArray.push(parseInt(el)) }
        else { newArray.push(parseInt(el)) }
    });

    newArray.sort();

    console.log(newArray);
    console.log(startArray);
    
    console.log(unsorted.sort((x,y)=>x-y))
}

bigSorting(startArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

you're very close :-)

```
    let startArray = [2643832795, 1, "3", 10, 3, 5];

    function bigSorting(unsorted) {
        const newArray = unsorted.map(x => parseInt(x, 10));
        newArray.sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1);
        return newArray;
    }

    console.log(startArray);
    console.log(bigSorting(startArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s sorting as it should. It sorts accordingly as it would sort a list of strings.

`var list = [2643832795, 1, "3", 10, 3, 5];`

When you write `list.sort()` it just sorts as would sort any list of strings according to each character's Unicode code point value.

So, 1 comes first then 2, 3 and so on. So even if it's 2643832795, it would come before 3.

If you want to sort this treating them as integers, you should supply a callback something like this:

```js
    var list = [2643832795, 1, "3", 10, 3, 5];
    var newList = list.map(i=>parseInt(i)); //Convert the strings in the list into integers
     newList.sort((a, b) => a-b); 
    
    console.log(newList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a lexicographical sort (e.g. convert objects to strings, and sort them in dictionary order), which is the default sort behavior in Javascript: Refer [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

In ES6, you can simplify this with arrow functions:

```
unsorted.sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

So this should be like:

```
let startArray = [2643832795, 1, "3", 10, 3, 5];

function bigSorting(unsorted) {
    let newArray = [];

    unsorted.forEach(el => { 
        if(typeof(el) == "string") 
        { newArray.push(parseInt(el)) }
        else { newArray.push(parseInt(el)) }
    });

    newArray.sort((a, b) => a - b);

    console.log(startArray);
    console.log(newArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it can help you.

```js
var numbers = [2, 5, 8, 7, 1, 6, 10, 3, 4, 9];
var asc = numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);  
console.log(asc); // Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]. Numeric sort

numbers = [2, 5, 8, 7, 1, 6, 10, 3, 4, 9];
var des = numbers.sort((a, b) => b - a);  
console.log(des); // Output: [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]. Numeric descending sort
```